# Bind Select List with FormBuilder Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

In Angular 2, creating a simple app but when formBuilder is attached with DOM control in case of select list , First option is coming blank - even if I provided some initial value in formBuilder that value is not coming to DOM element

Before FomBuilder

**Select List**

*Genral

LDAP*

After FomBuilder

**Select List**

*No option appearing initially*

*Genral

LDAP*
**File 1 - form.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({

        moduleId : module.id,
        selector : 'login',
        templateUrl : 'login.component.html',
        directives : [ REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES ],
})

export class LoginComponent{

        loginForm : FormGroup;

        constructor(private _router:Router,private _fb:FormBuilder){

                this.loginForm = _fb.group({
                    'username' : ['aa',[Validators.required]],
                    'password'  : ['',[Validators.required]],
                    'type'  : ['']
                })            
        }
      }

     loginUser(){
        console.log("Form is  = ",this.loginForm.controls);
     }
```

**File 2 - form.component.html**

```
        <form  [formGroup]="loginForm" id="form-login"(submit)="loginUser()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input  formControlName="username" type="text" id="login-username">                                
                    </div>                               
                </div>                        
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input formControlName="password" type="password" id="login-password">
                    </div>     
                </div>                                                                                                                                
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select formControlName="type" class="form-control input-lg" id="login-type">
                            <option value="Non-LDAP">General</option>                
                            <option value="LDAP">LDAP</option>                                    
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>                                                                                                                                
            </div>                   
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Login to Dashboard</button>
```

Comment: `'type'  : ['General']`

Comment: No my friend- Still select list is blank initially,  I already tried that as this provide initial value to DOM but not working

Comment: this may help you - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689049/drop-down-list-in-angular-2-model-driven-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689049/drop-down-list-in-angular-2-model-driven-form)

Answer (score 7):

You need to initiate the select value to 'value', not the text:

```
'type': ['Non-LDAP']
```

Comment: i think its been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689049/drop-down-list-in-angular-2-model-driven-form