# FormArray in Angular 4 using dynamic select option not working as intended

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I am trying to build a form with a form array, which has multiple drop down menus (all reactive, with value changing according to the option selected in the above select input).

This works pretty well when I am using a regular form group:

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="act">Act</label>
      <select id="act" formControlName="act" name="act" class="form-control">
          <option *ngFor="let act of acts" [value]="act.id">{{act.act.name}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

Here the act array changes on `valueChanges` of another select option.

However, in a FormArray, this is not working (for obvious reasons, that all nodes of **'act' select option** in the FormArray use the same '**act**' array).

This is the form array:
[image: Form Array]

The options for **ACT** changes when I select **LAW** like so:

[image: Ex 1]

However, when I select a new value for the **second Rule**, the ACT options are affected throughout all nodes of the array like so:

[image]

Is there any way to provide each FormArray node with a new array of options?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a small working example that we can test.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track but for formArray the `*ngFor` should iterate on the explicit controls of the form (https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/, the FormArray in the Template paragraph example).

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689049/drop-down-list-in-angular-2-model-driven-form share your complete HTML file and component file for further help